# Synchronize location of legend in multiple matplotlib axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

How can one synchronize the finding of the 'best' legend location in matplotlib using multiple axes?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 2)
axes[0].plot([0, 1], [0, 1], label="label1")
axes[1].plot([0, 1], [1, 0], label="label2")
for ax in axes:
    ax.legend(loc="best")
```

The code above will create two axes, where the 'best' position is evaluated for each plot individually. However, when having a grid of several plots, having the position automatically placed on the same spot (i.e. here loc=5 would do fine) for each sub-plot would be what I am searching for.

Workaround, obviously, would be not to let an algorithm decide the best position, but manually set a location. However, this location in my case is from model to model varying, therefore I would like to avoid this option. Second workaround, place the legend outside of the axis at a fixed position per sub plot.

Comment: `"best"` works per axis. So if you don't want that, you need to specify the location yourself.

Comment: You could run the first plot, see where best puts the first legend and then coerce the other legends to do th same thing.